# How do I open a link in Google chrome in Lua?

Tags: lua

The actual question. You can open the app via startApp, but how do I set an activity with a link?
startApp('com.android.chrome [https://stackoverflow.com/'](https://stackoverflow.com/%27))

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Lua can execute a command line with `os.execute("your command line")`. If the question is actually about "How do I start something on Android via command line?", it's more suitable for https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Здравствуйте, Егор. Необходимо запустить браузер с ссылкой через приложение AnkuLua на андроид.